# Your session has been expired when item added to cart at cart page in magento2

Tags: magento-2.3

When I was trying to add products on cart in magento2, but it showing an error. :(

[image: Your session has expired]

Comment: Please update what code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurs when form key is not valid.

```
if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Your session has expired')
            );
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
```

You should check form key is exist or not in Add to cart request. problem is due to this form key.

Also try these solutions as well

Yes, use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

**I hope it will helpful for you.**

Comment: Thanks:) It work (Yes, use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost).

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't work in local than it must be your SSL issue. Do active SSL and then open the site with https and then try to add a product in cart. This will fix your problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I changed 'web/unsecure/base_url', 'web/secure/base_url', 'web/cookie/cookie_domain' and related configurations by updating [core_config_data] or from Admin configuration, but it didn't work for me.

But, after applying SSL and configuring its https links in base URLs, this issue had been fixed.